# Complex SQL query to one table

Tags: mysql, sql, crosstab

There is a table:

```
event |id |timestamp
---------------------
event1|001|21-03-15
event2|001|22-03-15
event1|002|23-03-15
event2|002|24-03-15
```

What should be a request to display the result:

```
id |event1  |event2  |
----------------------
001|21-03-15|22-03-15|
002|23-03-15|24-03-15|
```

I *think* you first need to make a selection of unique `id`:

```
SELECT id FROM test GROUP BY id;
```

And then something like this:

```
SELECT timestamp
FROM   ... 
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM test GROUP BY id) AND event='event1';
```

Events are known in advance `('event1', 'event2')`.
If there are recurring events under one id, with different or the same timestamp, add columns to the result, for example:

```
id |event1  |event2  |event1  |event2  |
----------------------------------------
001|21-03-15|22-03-15|23-03-15|23-03-15|
002|23-03-15|24-03-15|NULL    |NULL    |
```

Comment: Can you expect that every ID will only have two events associated with it? And will they always be called "event1" and "event2"?

Comment: imo, a useful resource for MySQL queries: [Common MySQL Queries - Extending Chapter 9 of Get it Done with MySQL 5&6](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php). Have a look at `pivot tables`.

Comment: 1. every ID will have not only two events associated with, it willl have unexpected count of events
2. yes, events will always be called 'event1' and 'event2'

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a simple "pivot" or "crosstab" trick:

```
SELECT id
     , min(CASE event WHEN 'event1' THEN timestamp END) AS event1
     , min(CASE event WHEN 'event2' THEN timestamp END) AS event2
FROM   test
GROUP  BY id
ORDER  BY id;
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d51ff/1)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, query is looking like this:

```
SELECT A.id,GROUP_CONCAT(B.timestamp) AS event1, GROUP_CONCAT(C.timestamp) AS event2 FROM (select distinct id from test) A
   LEFT JOIN test B ON B.id=A.id and B.event='event1'
   LEFT JOIN test C ON C.id=A.id and C.event='event2' GROUP BY A.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join records that have `event1` with records that have `event2`:

```
SELECT t1.id as id, t1.timestamp as event1, t2.timestamp as event2 
FROM test t1 LEFT JOIN test t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.event = 'event1' and t2.event = 'event2'
```

The query assumes that you always have `event1`, so LEFT JOIN was used.

If you need to handle cases where only `event2` is available, you can emulate FULL OUTER JOIN as described in [Full Outer Join in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql)